# Read two files at the same time

Tags: c++, file

I have two files *names.txt* and *addresses.txt*, both of them have the same number of lines.

I want to read these two files at the same time, and for each line print a name followed by an address. But I read that I can't have two `ifstream`s at the same time.

I'm not looking for alternative ways of doing this, I'd like to do it this way

Comment: You can not have them at the exact same instant in time but you can have them very close

Comment: You can have 2 ifstreams at the same time. There’s no problem here whatsoever

Comment: "but I read that I can't have 2 ifstreams at the same time." - Your code CAN have many ifstreams open at the same time.  There is some limit, but it is quite a bit more the 2.

Comment: @JakeFreeman - Did the post change? I can not find the word 'exact' anywhere but these comments.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN my original interpretation was that it was exact same time not very close to it;

Comment: "I'd like to do it this way" - can you please submit a [MCVE] to describe 'this way'?

Comment: Whatever you read that said you can't have two `ifstream` objects at the same time was **wrong**.

Comment: @JakeFreeman - There is no 'very close to it' either.  Drive Head movements (access time 15 ms);  transfer from drive to cache to variables (in micro seconds); interleave with other OS-controlled disk access (unknown?); all are slow, finite efforts.  Perhaps the question is more like, "@DcCoO - do you think the read of the 2 files on normal desktop hardware will fail to meet some unstated performance requirement?  Can you share what you think performance requirement might be, or how much too slow a typical desktop disk drive might be fr this effort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read two `fstream`s at the same time for the purpose of this example would be this.

```
fstream names("names.txt");
fstream add("addresses.txt");
string n, a;
while(getline(names, n) && getline(add, a))
{
    cout<<n<<" "<<a<<endl;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this actually can be considered by reading at the same time, since nothing happens in between reading one file and another.

Comment: @Fureeish fair enough though without complex threading it cannot be at the exact same time.

Comment: Even with complex threading it cannot be done at the same time. Even setting a fixed timepoint to begin execution of reading does not guarantee it to start simultaneously

Comment: Even with threading your hardware may not support it. I mean a single hard drive will not read 2 files at the exact same time.

Comment: @Fureeish I updated my answer to reflect you suggestion